# How to wrap elements with nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, swap

Given a xpath say

Can I do something like:

```
doc.xpath("/html/body/a").wrap("<span></span>")
```

And wrap all the links with `span` tags?

Answer (score 6):

```
doc.xpath('/html/body/a').each{ |a| a.swap("<span>#{a}</span>") }
```

found better solution (edit according to @Phrogz)

```
doc.search('a').wrap('<span/>')
```

Comment: The `to_string` method calls `to_xml` ?

Comment: `to_s` returns `to_xml`/`to_html`, `to_str` returns `text`

Comment: Just as effective, without the duplication: `doc.css('a').wrap('<span/>')`